# Email and password on Facebook account

Tags: facebook

I opened a Facebook account for my husband using the same email as mine for my Facebook account. I have since purchased a new computer and when I enter my email address and password it says the password is wrong. When I use my husband's password it brings me to his Facebook page.

How do I access my Facebook page on my new computer if I can't use our email and *my* password?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how have you managed to set up two accounts with only one email address?

Comment: I think it is not possible to have a same email for different accounts because each one has a unique id which will be generated while creating the account hopefully can try resetting the password with the email will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think itt isn't possible to create two separate Facebook accounts from one email address, it is possible to use Facebook as two or more separate entities from the same Facebook account. Namely, Facebook allows you to create "Pages" for business and creative endeavors on which you embark and manage them from your personal profile account.

Btw, are you able to login with your new password(the one you used to create second) with new computer?